# BottomNavigationBar title not showing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-bottomnavigationview

Why the bottom navigation bar title not showing ? It suppose to show below the icon

```
class FlutterProject extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title = "Flutter Bottom Tab demo";

  @override
  GoalsListState createState() {
    return GoalsListState();
  }
}

class GoalsListState extends State<FlutterProject>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _cIndex = 0;

  void _incrementTab(index) {
    setState(() {
      _cIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    new One(),
    new Two(),
    new Three(),
    new Four(),
    new More()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: _children[_cIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _cIndex,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon:
                    Icon(Icons.graphic_eq, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                title: new Text('One')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.report_problem,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                title: new Text('Two')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.work, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                title: new Text('Three')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.domain, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                title: new Text('Four')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                title: new Text('Five')),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            _incrementTab(index);
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Title is indeed displayed but is in `white` color if you look closely. 
Just add a `color` to the text to display it properly.

`title: new Text('One', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))`

[image]

Comment: thanks,how can I let the text appear without clicking ?

Comment: You have `type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,`. If you change it to `fixed`, you'll have text appear by default.

Comment: @Darshan How can i get selected title of bottom navigation bar ??

Answer (score 39):

When more than 3 BottomNavigationBar items are provided the type if unspecified, changes to BottomNavigationBarType.shifting per https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar/BottomNavigationBar.html. This bit of information should be highlighted in the class's doc. It's easy to overlook where it is (I overlooked it).

Add type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed on BottomNavigationBar

```
BottomNavigationBar(
   type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
   items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[],
)
```

Answer (score 6):

U should use this code :

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
//use both properties
   type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
   showUnselectedLabels: true,
//-----------
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.icon1),
      label:'item 1',
   ),
   BottomNavigationBarItem(
     icon: Icon(Icons.icon2),
     label: 'item 2',
   ),
 ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is easy hack to show the label of the Navigation bar item

```
 BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Column(
              children: [
                new Icon(widget.currentTab == 2 ? Icons.dashboard_outlined : Icons.dashboard_outlined),
                Text("Homes")
              ],
            ),
            label: 'Home',

          ),
```